# Change the model value in the controller asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to update the model.Balance property from the AddCoin method. I brought the commented-out lines, as I also tried to do it, I still get 0. Other properties are associated with the repository and the values in them are updated normally.

```
//  private int balance;
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(HomeIndexViewModel model)
        {
            model.Drinks = drinkManager.GetAllDrink();
            model.Coins = coinManager.GetAllCoin();
         //   ModelState.Remove("Balance");
         //   model.Balance = balance;
            return View(model);
        }
public ActionResult AddCoin(int value, HomeIndexViewModel model)
        {
          //  balance = 150;
            var coin = coinManager.FindCoinById(value);
            // Если монеты доступны для ввода и их в автомате меньше 200
            if (coin.isAvailable == true && coin.NumberCoins < 200)
            {
                coin.NumberCoins += 1;
                model.Balance += coin.Value;
                coinManager.SaveCoin(coin);
            };
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you save in `coinManager.SaveCoin(coin);`, right? But `model.Balance += coin.Value;` doesn't really update `coin` and therefore isn't saved. You probably meant something like `coin.Balance += coin.Value;` or something similar

Comment: I checked, in that block all the values are assigned correctly. The Coin is stored in the correct value. model.Balance also gets the correct value, but it is not saved in the model.
Now I changed the AddCoin method to return RedirectToAction ("Index", model);, the values began to be saved. But model.Balance is completely overwritten after each new method call.

Comment: It seems easier to put this value in the storage too.

Comment: you lost me... you added missing parameter to `RedirectToAction() and it's now passed correctly. OK. now you have a different question - overwritten *where*? *When*? You may want to accept this answer - and start a new question for new problem...